# Stopwords/synonyms/etc file for ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I used to work with Solr and it would have configuration folder that would contain stopwords, synonyms, etc files. Every time you would make a change, you can use Zookeeper to download conf file and then upload it and distribute it across all servers in the cluster.

New to ElasticSearch, so pardon the question: Is there a way for me to automatically create such files and have Zookeeper or something else to distribute it automatically instead of manual step (or Puppet scripts)

According to this: http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/using-synonyms.html files must be present, but it does not mention how.

Also, I found this: https://github.com/lindstromhenrik/elasticsearch-analysis-file-watcher-synonym not sure if it is working. Date on it does not seem too promising.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... it seems that you have to use such thing as Puppet or Chef. Weird that ES would make it so complicated.

> Synonym files must be replicated exactly between hosts. If this is not
>   carefully managed bad things can happen. At Found, this is done
>   automatically when you upload a custom bundle with a synonyms file in
>   it. If you manage your own servers, be sure to use a configuration
>   management tool like Ansible, Chef, or Puppet to synchronize these
>   files between hosts, otherwise you may find that synonyms are
>   interepreted differently depending on which host is handling which
>   requests.

https://www.found.no/foundation/text-analysis-part-2/

Answer (score 0):

How to distributed the file is out of scope of my abilities to answer your question, however:

An external file for "Synonyms", like "StopWords", are read in two circumstances:

- when you create the Analyzer
- when you restart your node

The guide has a section on how to [update the stopwords](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/using-stopwords.html#updating-stopwords) list. This applies to synonyms as well.

In my practice I found it easier to provide the synonyms directly within the JSON payload. Safes me from "knowing too much" about the actual infrastructure regarding servers, file locations, etc.